# Connecting 2 arrays, a string array and a number array

Tags: c++, arrays

So, I have an array called `rainfall` which has data of rainfall for 12 months stored in. And also a string array for the months (jan,feb...). And I will have to sort the rainfall array from highest to lowest. How do I connect this 2 arrays, so I can print them out together properly after sorting out the rainfall array.

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void selectionSort(double array[],int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex, maxValue;
    for(startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        maxValue = array[startScan];
        for(int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if (array[index] > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = array[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        array[startScan] = maxValue;
    }
}
void highestfunction(double highestrainfall[], string monthtemp[])
{
   double highest;
    highest = highestrainfall[0];
    string highestmonth = "January";
    for (int count = 1; count < 12; count++)
    {
        if (highestrainfall[count] > highest)
            {
            highest = highestrainfall[count];
            highestmonth = monthtemp[count];
            }
    }
    cout << highestmonth << " has highest amount of rainfall: " << highest << " ml" << endl;
}
void lowestfunction(double lowestrainfall[], string monthtemp[])
{
    double lowest;
    lowest = lowestrainfall[0];
    string lowestmonth = "January";
    for (int count = 1; count < 12; count++)
    {
        if(lowestrainfall[count] < lowest)
        {
            lowest = lowestrainfall[count];
            lowestmonth = monthtemp[count];
        }
    }
    cout << lowestmonth << " has lowest amount of rainfall: " << lowest << " ml" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    string months[] = { "January",
                        "February",
                        "March",
                        "April",
                        "May",
                        "June",
                        "July",
                        "August",
                        "September",
                        "October",
                        "November",
                        "December"};
    double rainfall[12];
    double total = 0;
    double average;
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < 12; count++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the total rainfall (in milliliter) of " << months[count] << ": ";
        cin >> rainfall[count];
        while(rainfall[count] < 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid input!!! Please try again. " << endl;
            cout << "Enter the total rainfall (in milliliter) of " << months[count] << ": ";
            cin >> rainfall[count];
        }
    }
    for (count = 0; count <12; count++)
    {
        total += rainfall[count];
    }
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed;
    cout << "The total rainfall for a year is: " << total << " ml" << endl;
    average = (total / 12);
    cout << "The average rainfall monthly rainfall is " << average << " ml" << endl;
    highestfunction(rainfall, months);
    lowestfunction(rainfall, months);
    selectionSort(rainfall, 12);
    cout << "List of the months, sorted in order of rainfall from highest to lowest" << endl;
    for(count = 0; count < 12; count++)
    {
        cout << rainfall[count] <<" ml" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Input/Output provide, please

Comment: You could have an array of [`std:pair`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)

Comment: or use a std::map<key,value> where your key is the month and the value is the rainfall

Comment: @FirstStep Even better! He needs it sorted so it could be the other way arround, key rainfall, and value month

Comment: @FirstStep this map could be used for sorting the values?

Comment: i already sorted out the rainfall array, now i just need to connect them together. so i  could print out the month along rainfall correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want label each rainfall with a month.
Therefore you can define a struct. For example;

```
struct RainfallDefinition
{ 
   string month; 
   double rainfall;
}
```

now you can use array of RainfallDefinition and sort with respect to rainfall attribute.

If you do not use structs, you can use [pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair). However, in my opinion using struct is more reliable and readable. You can extend your RainfallDefinition any time. For example, you can also add `int year;` , `int day;` attributes etc.  and then you can sort without losing any info.

Comment: Thank You. yes, that what i want to do, but i haven't learned "struct". Is there anyway else?

Comment: Struct is easy to learn (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_structures.htm). You can learn in 10 mins and apply your case easily. Do not use map for this case. Aim of the map is mapping values and keys. In your case rainfall cannot be a key. Map works like give the key and get the value very fast. If the problem is sorting, you cannot give the rainfall as a key, right? Because you need to get key. You can use vector pair. Comparing vector pair, using struct is easy in this case

Comment: @sam Why couldn't you give the rainfall value as key? It would accomplish the sorting he seeks. But anyway, the struct seems a more didactic approach in this case

Comment: @Nacho Think about that, rainfall[0] is 12.5 rainfall[1] is 13.78 and goes like this. And you want to sort the map.(?!) In this case, you have to loop in a for and "get all the keys" to sort. However, the idea of map is giving the key and getting the value. If you were going to look at every index of something somehow, working with arrays or vector is good.

Comment: @sam [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) already sorts the keys in ascending order, OP wanted to sort the array in descending order (ordered by rainfall). So you would just need to fill the map and traverse it in reverse order (rbegin). The only inconvenience would appear if two or more months have the same rainfall value, in which case you should use a [std::multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/). But as I said this will be hard for some like OP who seems to be starting to learn the language. That's why I like your answer.

Answer (score -1):

i could suggest a simple algo for it...
take two arrays one array of strings which contains the months...name it 
`

```
string month[12]; 
/* i.e. 12 months initially give em the month names in regular order...i.e. starting from jan to dec...*/
```

second array would be a 2 dimensional array...
`

```
int rainfall[12][2];
// rainfall[i][j] likewise you know rows and columns respectively i m considering
```

`

put values in it initially like

`

```
rainfall[0][0]=150; // this is the amount of rainfall in litre or whatever unit
rainfall[0][1]=0; 
/* here 2nd column contains the index of month in string, i.e. for now it is 0 that is January...likewise*/
```

now you sort the rainfall array for the values in `rainfall[i][0]` and where ever you swap two values for sorting... suppose you swap `rainfall[1][0]` to `rainfall[3][0]` then in the next statement in which you swap them...also swap their respective indices...
so in the end u would be having array rainfall in a sorted manner so when u want `rainfall[i][0]` 's month.. you can check it by `month[rainfall[i][1]]` ...

**This thing can also be done using pointers and linked list...even a little more efficiently but i did this because when i have choice between using linked list using pointers and without it... i prefer without it

**this could also be done using structure but here is the most organic way i found...

Comment: Could be a nice answer for a C question. Why not use all the "already tested and optimized" features and containers the STL offers?

Comment: @Nacho nice suggestion mate...it could be done... its just the thing that i usually try to do things C style for first..i mean atleast for first attempt...also without using header library functions( here without using means minimalist use)...but overall moral of the story it could be used...

Comment: Ok, though you shouldn't try to do things "C style" first if you are writing C++ code. No need to re-invent the wheel every time, just use what you have at hand, will be faster, safer and cleaner. For instance, what happens if you try to access your C array with an index that doesn't exist? Nothing good I'm afraid.

Comment: well said i would say...would keep that thing in mind and would implement that in practice soon... :) thanks mate